# How do i suppress a ssh-add passphrase prompt?

Tags: cmd.exe, io

Whenever i run `ssh-add` in cmd it outputs a passphrase prompt.

```
ssh-add "%~%\.ssh\id_rsa"
Enter passphrase for C:\Users\Kristian Welsh\.ssh\id_rsa:
```

I would like to suppress this text to add my own, but redirecting stdout doesn't help.

```
ssh-add "%~%\.ssh\id_rsa" >nul
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Are you saying that you don't want to have to enter the passphrase, or are you saying that you want to enter the passphrase, but you want to suppress `ssh-add`'s prompt?  If it's the second, what happens if you say `ssh-add "%~%\.ssh\id_rsa" 2>nul`?

Comment: I still want to have to enter the passphrase, i just don't want that text to be there. Regarding  `ssh-add "%~%\.ssh\id_rsa" 2>nul` it still asks for a passphrase, just fails silently when improperly set up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to change the prompt with custom text outside of changing the code. However, there are two ways around it:

1. remove the passphrase from the key
2. write an expect wrapper around ssh-add that provides the passphrase for you

Comment: I still want it to be passphrase protected. I just don't want the text to appear.

Comment: Then your best option is to wrap it around expect

Comment: No, i don't want the passphrase stored anywhere in a file, i want to have to provide it manually.

Comment: Not 100% but I don't think you can do what you want without changing the source for ssh-add. I don't believe theres, for example, an NLS file that houses the strings, I think its all compiled in. Perhaps someone smarter than me can answer more fully